# How to write correct link of a file located in root directory in my component.ts in angular

Tags: angular, forms

I found this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52009420/how-to-send-angular-6-form-without-backend) but I am having problem with putting the right link to my php file. I am having the test.php file in the root directory in my angular project, please how do I specify correect link to the file in my component:

```
this.http.post("link to the php file.", email).subscribe();
```

I did this:

```
this.http.post("test.php", email).subscribe();
```

but was getting: http://localhost:4200/test not found in the console. How do I correctly link the test.php.

Comment: You want to place the php file in the `src/assets` directory. Then you can request like `this.http.post("/assets/test.php", email)`

Comment: Ok I will try that..

Comment: "Http failure response for http://localhost:4200/assets/test.php: 404 Not Found"

Comment: Check `angular.json` once whether the assets folder is mentioned there. Like `assets: ["src/assets"]`

Comment: Yes the angular.json is fine. And when I run  localhost:4200/assets/test.php directly on the browser, there was no error, the file got test.php file got downloaded. But posting the form still gives: "Http failure response for localhost:4200/assets/test.php: 404 Not Found".